# WSO2 Cloud Gateway and StratosLive

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

Is WSO2 Cloud Gateway supported in StratosLive?  Is there self-service setup?  I would like to expose an internal web service (behind corporate firewalls) to WSO2 ESB on StratosLive and Cloud Gateway may be one solution...

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 CG is supported in StratosLive and we are in the process of deploying CG(and other services) in StratosLive. Please check back in couple days.